# Python: What is the point of `import X as X` where X the same?

Tags: python, python-import

In `aiohttp` I found many statements with `import X as X`. Why it was done like that?

[Link for the file](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/blob/135cb1656ab4434927363a05245b6b43cfd04595/aiohttp/__init__.py)

Comment: I also have seen this in Blacksheep. I think there is an meaning about it

Comment: FastAPI does this too: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/blob/440d2d2d1a72867b3f38b5c7359e021cccbfea8b/fastapi/__init__.py

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did not know the answer, but the history of the linked source file [revealed it](https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/issues/3868).

The construct `from SOMEWHERE import X as X` (with the same `X`) is required to silence a warning from `mypy --strict` about [not re-exported module](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-no-implicit-reexport). AFAIK, adding the `as X` to `import X` has no effect to the program itself.

[`mypy`](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting_started.html) is an optional static type analyzer and apparently the developers decided to use it and to use it in the strict mode.